# AngularJS problems evaluating regex ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm using `ng-pattern` argument in input text to limit input to numeric values:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="numericField" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" />
```

But there is a strange behavior in regex evaluation: starting and ending spaces are ignored...

So if I insert these values (for example) I get different results:

`'   123   '` pattern matched

`'   123 4343 '` pattern not matched

In my case white spaces are not allowed (in any position of the string).

**Update** I need to solve the problem also for other inputs allowing char values (i.e. email)

So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `ng-trim="false"` to your input text:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="numericField" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-trim="false" />
```

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ANxmv/974/)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="numericfield" />
```

html5 behaviour is implemented by angular in older browsers.